# Matching multiple MAC address in arp-scan's output

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi, arp

I'm using this `sudo arp-scan --localnet | awk '/b8:27:/ { print $1 }'` to find Raspberry pis on my network based on a partial Mac address and I was wondering how I can display multiple awk print results using one single line without repeating the same command?

Raspberry pi's use the following ranges:

```
dc:a6:
b8:27:
e4:5f:
28:cd:c1:
```

This works, but only with one single Mac.

`sudo arp-scan --localnet | awk '/b8:27:/ { print $1 }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them all to the regex (at least that's what I **think** you were asking for, your question isn't very well worded) - the pipe `|` functions as an `or`:

```
sudo arp-scan --localnet | awk '/b8:27:|dc:a6:|e4:5f:|28:cd:c1:/ { print $1 }'
```

Comment: Thank You it worked, yes I know it was not properly addressed according to some people understanding, the problem is maybe cause I don't know how to address certain things to make everybody understand.

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you. Should I take the liberty to make your question a bit clearer? @SphereWallpapers